# How to make an AES-256 keypair in openssl/OSX

Tags: macos, openssl, aes, encryption-symmetric

I need to generate a keypair and give the public key to someone. They say it needs to be:

- AES-256 CBC 128-bit block size.
- random Initialization Victor IV of 16b fixed length.
- PKCS7Padding

I don't even know if these are the defaults or not or even if I'm asking in the right place. How can I make a key like this?

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements cannot be correct. AES is a symmetric algorithm, which means both parties should have the same *secret* key. Key pairs are generated for asymmetric encryption such as RSA.

Most of the time AES and RSA are used together for encryption. This is called hybrid encryption: a random AES key is generated and used to encrypt the plaintext. Then the AES key is encrypted with the RSA public key (using OAEP padding, for instance). Then the resulting ciphertext and the encrypted key are send to the other party, which can decrypt the AES key using the private key, and then the ciphertext with the AES key.

If you just need to give a secret key you *must* use secure transport. An AES key can be 256 bits secure random key, which can easily be extracted from `/dev/urandom`, e.g.:

```
dd bs=1 count=32 if=/dev/urandom of=aes-256-key.bin
```

for RSA, use the `openssl` command line, for instance.

Comment: Is there someplace I can go to learn the absolute basics of this? I feel like I'm understanding every third word.

Comment: check out this slideshow: http://www.slideshare.net/jaytaph/alice-bob-public-key-cryptography-101-7647522

Comment: @mti2935 OK-ish slides, although 2 mistakes at first glance. Signing is not using encryption, it is using modular exponentiation. It is wrong to think of it using encryption (PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for signing and PSS padding schemes could have been mentioned). And TLS is not on top of HTTP of course, it is on top of TCP.